# Trouble with Eclipse's Android Emulator view

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I'm on Eclipse and starting the Android Emulator, it just stays sticked at the top of my PC screen, being impossible for me to see the top of the emulator.
I've tried all the methods found here, the -scale in Run configurations --> Target, the skin... whatever, and I just wanna split up the emulator from the top of my PC screen, not working with all those said methods.. if anyone knows how, I would be so grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this trouble until yesterday.  There are a few methods to take care of it.  Right click on the emulator and select Move (if using Windows) and press your down arrow button.  Or you can try this software [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/), which is what I use.

Comment: Sorry, forgot it! Done now :)